# c++ writing operator>, I seem to be approaching the comparison improperly, how can I do this properly?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

This is the error I'm receiving:

```
error C2662: 'std::string node<std::string>::getItem(void)' : cannot convert 'this' pointer from 'const node<std::string>' to 'node<std::string> &'
```

From my understanding, *this* is a pointer and *rhs* is an address (&) so it can't compare them properly. If my understanding is correct, I'm not sure how to fix this or what an appropriate approach would be.

This is my full method code. getItem() returns a String in the instance I'm working with (technically a T) which is why I ?falsely? assumed that I could have the method return the string and then directly compare them with ">":

```
template <typename T>
bool node<T>::operator>(const node<T>& rhs) const {
    return (this->getItem() > rhs.getItem());
}
```

Here is getItem() for reference if I didn't explain it very well:

```
template <typename T>
T node<T>::getItem() {
    return item;
}
```

Overloading this operator is in an attempt to get this line to work properly:

```
storage.sort(std::greater<node<T>>());
```

Answer (score 3):

The issue here is that "getItem()" is not declared "const" yet is being invoked from a "const" function. To fix this, change:

```
getItem() {
```

to:

```
getItem() const {
```

Comment: Won't he want to change the return type to be a const reference also?

Comment: Thank you! That seems to have done the trick. Looking back at the error message now it makes more sense. My mind had skipped over the "const" and lack of.

Comment: I'd suggest making the comparison a nonmember instead.